# sas search value across column with array and extract values of next 12 columns

Tags: sas

I want to count the number of 'noncure' occurrences across different columns with some condition, at different position dates. How do I search for the occurrence of 12 '1's across columns.

[UPDATE]
I've modified my dataset and think this is the best way to populate out my desired results.

This is a sample of my raw data

```
    data have;
    input acct flg1 flg2 flg3 flg4 flg5 flg6 flg7 flg8 flg9 flg10 flg11 flg12 flg13 flg14 flg15 flg16 flg17 flg18 flg19 flg20 flg21 flg22 flg23 flg24 flg25;
    datalines;
    AA 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 
    run;
```

The numbers on `flg` represent months - eg flg1 = jan10, flg2 = feb10 & so on.
To get noncure, certain conditions have to be fulfilled.

1. flg(i) has to be 0
2. noncure only happens if there is a minimum of 12 consecutive flg of '1' in the future
3. an account can have more than 1 noncure incidents

The computation of noncure should look like this (Refer to image for a better view - highlighted in green)
[image: Computation]

AA 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

- noncure1 is 1 because flg1 is 0 and the next 12 1 is at flg9
- noncure2 is 1 because flg2 is 0 and the next 12 1 is at flg9
- noncure4 is 0 because flg4 is not 0
- noncure23 is 0 because even though flg23 is 0, there is no following consecutive 12 at flg25 (only one count of '1')

I'm having problems searching for my first instance of consecutive 12 '1' at flg(i).
I was thinking of doing an array to populate out position of consecutive 12 (eg nc_pos) then do i to nc_pos - something along the lines of

```
nc_pos =  <search for 12 consecutive occurrence of '1' from flg(i)> **I don't know the code for this**
if flg(i) = 0 then do i to nc_pos;
noncure_tag = 1;
obs_pos = i;
```

FYI I have few hundred thousand accounts with a total of 84 months and their starting positions are different (eg flg1 could be null and the first 0 or 1 may appear at flg3).

My final output should look something like the image file labelled TARGET highlighted in yellow.
[image: Target]

Comment: Regarding *I've managed to...*  - **show you code** that achieved that.  Otherwise this is just a code writing request.

Comment: Hi Richard, the only thing I've managed to do is create the pos column - i've yet to figure out what logic or steps to apply to achieve the final table.
if it helps, this is how i got my pos -
        if first.item then pos = 1; else pos +1;

Comment: Thanks for trying to supply input data and trying to give a full explanation of what is required. Please edit your question if you need to clarify or correct anything about the problem; you can still respond to comments, but the question should have all the latest and correct information in it. I have tried to run your initial data step to create the have data set, but it is not showing the same data as in the data lines, e.g. the first column should be character. You say "ntd_dt has a value when npl_flg changes from 1 to 0 the following month (aka pos)." but obs 11 is x when npl_flg is 1 next

Comment: You show a `cure state @ 49` tag for 44 to 48, and a `CO state @ 57` tag for 44 to 54 (sans 49, 55, 56).  Is it possible the data would indicate an additional cure or CO beyond 57 ? If so would each additional state also start from `44` ?